# Given the mid-points of ellipse, its orientation, minor and major axis length, get n points on the ellipse

Tags: python, opencv

I have multiple images of bees in my dataset. I am also given the midpoint, orientation and major and minor axis length of each bee. Now, I want a mask that surrounds the bee. I was thinking of extracting around 15-20 points around the bees, that would represent 1 bee. How do I go about doing that?

Can I somehow use OpenCV to get the points around the ellipse?

**EDIT**

After using cv2.ellipse, I have an image like this. I want around 15-20 corner points for each bee.  [image: this is just the sub-image of the complete image]

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_with_blue_blobs, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
epsilon = 0.01*cv2.arcLength(contours[0],True)
green_dots = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[0],epsilon,True)
```

**Problem** - green_dots variable just has the corners of the image.

Comment: See the [parametric equation](https://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamellipse.html) of an ellipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [OpenCV to draw an ellipse](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html).

```
cv2.ellipse(img,(256,256),(100,50),0,0,360,255,-1)
```

You could calculate the points, or you can just find them using OpenCV:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
epsilon = 0.01*cv2.arcLength(contours[0],True)
green_dots = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[0],epsilon,True)
```

[image: ellipse]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the green_dots always have just 4 points and those are the 4 corners of the image. Can you please help?

Comment: @MadhavThakker You can change the epsilon value to get more or fewer points in the contour approximation.